# If [ is a builtin and [[ is a keyword, then what is ((?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/590335/128176), `[` is a builtin and `[[` is a keyword. Since they can be regarded as command, everything after `[` and `[[` is regarded as command arguments and should be separated by spaces, until they meet final argument `]` and `]]`

But what is the type of `((` ?

```
type ((
```

will give an error:

```
 bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('.
```

I found that spaces is not relevant inside `(( ))`.

```
echo $((1+1))
echo $(( 1+1))
echo $(( 1+1 ))
echo $(( 1+  1))
echo $(( 1  +  1  ))
```

are all the same

---

**summary**

according to [POSIX standard doc: Grouping Commands section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_01)

> If a character sequence beginning with "((" would be parsed by the
>   shell as an arithmetic expansion if preceded by a '$', shells which
>   implement an extension whereby "((expression))" is evaluated as an
>   arithmetic expression may treat the "((" as introducing as an
>   arithmetic evaluation instead of a grouping command. A conforming
>   application shall ensure that it separates the two leading '('
>   characters with white space to prevent the shell from performing an
>   arithmetic evaluation.

And the arithmetic evaluation inside `((...))` is conformed with C style. So space is not relevant inside `((...))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`((` is not a word. Unlike `[` and `[[`, it isn't part of the list of words that constitutes a command. The best way to think of it is as punctuation. Actually, it's two punctuation characters, which may or may not be combined in a single token depending on the context. It's similar to things like `>&` and `||` in that respect. Punctuation characters are treated in an ad-hoc way by the shell's lexer/parser.

`((` is half of an operator, the other half being `))`. Together they make the arithmetic expression operator, which has an “outfix” syntax. The grammatical structure of shell languages such as bash doesn't follow traditional programming language syntax very neatly (for example there are very strong ties between lexical analysis and grammatical parsing, because punctuation characters have a meaning that depends on the grammatical context), so there aren't always neatly-fitting words.

`type` can only give you information about words that can appear in simple commands and about keywords, not about how the shell's lexer/parser works.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57840/discussion-on-answer-by-gilles-if-is-a-builtin-and-is-a-keyword-then-what).

Comment: @terdon, maybe so (and I agree it's too long to put in comments), but that discussion IMO is also interesting and complements this answer well. That Q&A is bound to be chatty anyway as there's no really official (or non-official) formalisation of the shell syntax (other than the POSIX grammar which is also incomplete/approximative), so is bound to be at least a bit _opinion-based_.